# Create a moving sum of past levels of a variable, summed over for each level of 3 other variables, in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data.frame of the following structure (panel data), with 16 levels of time(quarters) 14 levels of geo (countries) and 20 levels of citizen, each of them repeating accordingly in the dataframe.

```
  time     geo                          citizen      X 
2008Q1 Belgium                      Afghanistan     22
2008Q1 Belgium                          Armenia     10
2008Q1 Belgium                       Bangladesh     25
2008Q1 Belgium Democratic Republic of the Congo     55
2008Q1 Belgium      China (including Hong Kong)      5
2008Q1 Belgium                          Eritrea      8
```

I would like to create a new column lets say MOVSUM where it will sum variable **X** for each level of citizen and geo and time for the previous 4 quarters, so that I would have for each quarter, t, how many X's of each citizen in each geo were available during t-4 to t-1 quarters.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what have you tried? Please review this question for suggestions to make a better *reproducible* example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: This question has two components. 1) Calculate a moving sum. 2) Aggregate the results for different subgroups. Both of these have *many* similar questions and answers here on SO. Where exactly do you get stuck?

Comment: I haven't found sth that suits my problem preciesly, mainly because possibly I was looking at the problem as one component. As I am a beginner in R, I haven't done anything as I do not know how.